# Converting a soundcloud username to userid

Tags: soundcloud, userid

I want to embed the soundcloud widget (ex: http://www.sabbatella.com/soundcloud.htm) of lots of users in their profiles. I have all their usernames but not the user ids, which are necessary to embed the code.

Could you please explain me how to convert a soundcloud username to its userid in the most simple way? Ex: http://www.soundcloud.com/nightclubber is user id  32661578.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need the user id. Embed the player with the user's profile page as the `url` parameter and it will automatically be resolved when the player starts. It will mean one additional ajax request before the player loads, but it's probably not too bad.

For example, these two are equivalent:

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//soundcloud.com/spadgos
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/6431392
```

Alternatively, you can use the [resolve](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) endpoint to resolve a permalink to a user

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https%3A//soundcloud.com/spadgos&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to put this widget without using iframe ?